# Jenkin Android Build Issue

Tags: android, jenkins, build, transform

I am getting issue of **Failed to transform aar files** while trying to build the android into Jenkin. Everything working fine while building using android studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QUFD.png)
following is the gradle file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ0Gk.png)

Comment: Please post formatted error text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please attach proper screen shot with complete error or attach text it will better option to answer your issue for community!!